# S.M.A.R.T SSD - What does this stats means?

Tags: ssd, info

I bought an Adata SSD some days ago and noticed this on S.M.A.R.T statistics:

Disk Info:

[image: Disk Info]

Disk Sentinel:

[image: Disk Sentinel]

What does the values for "Total Wearlevel Count", "Reallocation Event Count" and "UltraDMA CRC Error Count" means? Is it some sort of error? I am thinking of returning this ssd, because it also came with more than 1TB of total host writes as you can see on CDI image, so i'm wondering if I should mention any possible error in the s.m.a.r.t stats as well.

Comment: These three attributes have 0 values, why do you think there's something wrong with them?

Comment: I showed it to someone else and he said that these attributes had an error, I didn't thought it was the case so I wanted to be sure asking someone who understands it better than me, but looks like the drive is fine then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values are normed to 100, lower is worse.

Reallocation Event Count = number of times a bad sector got re-allocated, that is, replaced with a spare sector because it cannot be longer written.

UltraDMA CRC error count = number of CRC (cyclic redudancy check) when using DMA (direct memory access) with "ultra" speeds.

I don't know how "total wearlevel count" is calculated.

Your values are 100 everywhere, this is a healthy disk.

Comment: Thanks for the help!